# MYSQL Returns Date out of order

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I am listing all the news articles by month, and year, and how many articles occured during that month...

However I noticed that in the new year it is sorting by month only and not

Here is my SQL

```
$archive1_sql = "SELECT YEAR(`ndate`) AS 'year', MONTH(`ndate`) AS 'month', COUNT(`nid`) AS 'count'  FROM `weaponsnews` GROUP BY YEAR(`ndate`), MONTH(`ndate`) DESC";
```

And it returns

```
December 2012 (1)
November 2012 (11)
October 2012 (6)
September 2012 (8)
August 2012 (16)
July 2012 (8)
June 2012 (6)
May 2012 (12)
April 2012 (4)
March 2012 (2)
February 2012 (4)
January 2013 (1)
```

What I want it to do is sort like this

```
January 2013 (1)
December 2012 (1)
November 2012 (11)
October 2012 (6)
September 2012 (8)
August 2012 (16)
July 2012 (8)
June 2012 (6)
May 2012 (12)
April 2012 (4)
March 2012 (2)
February 2012 (4)
```

How do I do that?

Comment: you don't have an `order by` clause, so you're getting back data in whatever order mysql decides it wants to send it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add DESC with YEAR too

```
SELECT
  YEAR(`ndate`) AS 'year',
  MONTH(`ndate`) AS 'month',
  COUNT(`nid`) AS 'count'
FROM `weaponsnews`
GROUP BY YEAR(`ndate`) , MONTH(`ndate`)
ORDER BY YEAR(`ndate`) DESC , MONTH(`ndate`) DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the `GROUP BY` to:

```
GROUP BY YEAR(`ndate`) DESC, 
         MONTH(`ndate`) DESC
```

If there is no `ORDER BY`, MySQL has an (non-standard SQL) feature that it orders the results according to the `GROUP BY` ordering. It also allows the `ASC` and `DESC` keywords there.

From MySQL docs **[`SELECT` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html)**:

> - If you use `GROUP BY`, output rows are sorted according to the `GROUP BY` columns **as if you had an `ORDER BY` for the same columns**. To avoid the overhead of sorting that `GROUP BY` produces, add `ORDER BY NULL`:
>
>   ```
>   SELECT a, COUNT(b) FROM test_table GROUP BY a ORDER BY NULL;
>   ```
> - MySQL extends the `GROUP BY` clause so that you can also specify `ASC` and `DESC` after columns named in the clause:
>
>   ```
>   SELECT a, COUNT(b) FROM test_table GROUP BY a DESC;
>   ```

Comment: Thanks Both answers are right, I am going to give him the answer tho cuz he answered first, but thanks I did not know I could use DESC twice, but it makes sense now that I think about it

Answer (score 2):

To get your records in (reversed) chronological order, use "order by ndate DESC":

```
SELECT
  YEAR(`ndate`) AS 'year',
  MONTH(`ndate`) AS 'month',
  COUNT(`nid`) AS 'count'
FROM `weaponsnews`
GROUP BY YEAR(`ndate`) , MONTH(`ndate`)
ORDER BY ndate DESC
```

Then you can group by whatever you want (days, weeks...), you do not need to change your 'order by' statement.

Comment: If one groups by `WEEKDAY(ndate)`, how should `ORDER BY ndate` behave?

Comment: @ypercube: Randomly :) If your groups correspond to some chronological order, this will do the trick. If you mix mondays with tuesdays, then mysql will pick some random record in each group and compare them. Now if you group by year, week AND weekday, then you get your groups in chronological order.